# Array methods using splice

Tags: arrays, methods

I want to add 2 numbers at the beginning of array using splice method . can some one explain why the 2nd method gives me an empty array as output?.

```js
const arrayold = [5, 6, 7, 8];
arrayold.splice(0, 0, 1, 2);
const arrayNew = arrayold;
console.log(arrayNew);
```

```js
const arrayold = [5, 6, 7, 8];

const arrayNew = arrayold.splice(0, 0, 1, 2);
console.log(arrayNew);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it **returns** *a list of deleted objects*!

The actual modified thing is in the variable/s

Like it is in the first case, you decided not to do  `var o1=o2.splice( /*arguments*/ )`; but `var _new=_old` instead.

You can read more at mdn about what splice modifies and what it returns!

Answer (score 0):

splice() modifies the source array and returns an array of the removed items. Since you didn't ask to remove any items, you get an empty array back. It modifies the original array to insert your new items

Answer (score 0):

```js
const arrayold = [5, 6, 7, 8];
const arrayNew= arrayold.splice(0, 0, 1, 2);
console.log(arrayNew);
```

The splice method generally return the removed item from an array. So In your second sceanrio arrayold.splice(0,0,1,2) you are not removing any element as you have mentioned 0 that's why it is giving you empty array